Evaluate the integral $ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( 5 \cdot \text{sinc}(5 t) - 7 \cdot \text{sinc}(7 t) \right)^2 \, dt $
Problem Statement:
Given:
\begin{equation}
x(t) = 5 \cdot \text{sinc}(5 t), \quad y(t) = 7 \cdot \text{sinc}(7 t)
\end{equation}
where $\text{sinc}(t) = \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}$, Find the value of $ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( x(t) - y(t) \right)^2 \, dt $.
I have solved this problem based on the Parseval's theorem and  I am looking for alternative or possibly more elegant approaches.
My Solution:
By using the Fourier transform, we can solve this integral in the frequency domain, based on the Parseval's theorem, which states:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(t)|^2 \, dt = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |F(\omega)|^2 \, d\omega
\end{equation}
Where $ F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_{\omega} \{f(t)\}$ represents the continuous Fourier transform of $f(t)$ and $\omega=2 \pi f$ is frequency in radians per second.
For real signals $ x(t) $ and $ y(t) $, and assuming $ x(t) - y(t) = f(t) $, we have:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(t)|^2 \, dt = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |F(\omega)|^2 \, d\omega
\end{equation}
Thus:
\begin{equation}
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x(t) - y(t))^2 \, dt = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |X(\omega) - Y(\omega)|^2 \, d\omega
\end{equation}
Now, we need to compute $ X(\omega) $ and $ Y(\omega) $ and substitute them into the above integral.
Using the Fourier transform, we have:
\begin{equation}
x(t) = 5 \cdot \text{sinc}(5 t) \implies X(\omega) = \Pi\left( \frac{\omega}{10 \pi} \right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y(t) = 7 \cdot \text{sinc}(7 t) \implies Y(\omega) = \Pi\left( \frac{\omega}{14 \pi} \right)
\end{equation}
Where, $ \Pi\left( \frac{\omega}{2 \omega_{0}} \right) $ represents a rectangular function (or pulse function) with a height of $1$ that spans from $-\omega_{0}$ to $\omega_{0}$.
To calculate $ |X(\omega) - Y(\omega)|^2 $:
For $ X(\omega) $, the rectangular function  is from $-5 \pi$ to $5 \pi$, and for $ Y(\omega) $, it is from $-7 \pi$ to $7 \pi$.
The difference $ Y(\omega) - X(\omega) $ results in a rectangular function spanning from $-7 \pi$ to $7 \pi$ with a removed section from $-5 \pi$ to $5 \pi$.
Finally, the integral will be:
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |Y(\omega) - X(\omega)|^2 \, d\omega = \frac{1}{2\pi} \left( \int_{-7 \pi}^{-5 \pi} 1 \, d\omega + \int_{5 \pi}^{7 \pi} 1 \, d\omega \right) = \frac{2 \pi+2 \pi}{2 \pi}=2.
\end{equation}

Since$$\sin ax\sin bx=\sin^2\frac{(a+b)x}{2}-\sin^2\frac{(a-b)x}{2}$$takes care of the cross term, you just need to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x$ by any of countless methods then keep rescaling $x$.

If $a,,b>0$, you can with my hint prove$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty(a\operatorname{sinc}ax-b\operatorname{sinc}bx)^2\mathrm{d}x=|a-b|.$$(The other common definition $\operatorname{sinc}t:=\frac{\sin t}{t}$ would make the integral $\pi$ times bigger.)

@J.G. This makes the problem much simpler. Thanks

I made it more general. Have a look at the edit. By the way, notice how good is @J.G.'s solution.

With $$\text{sinc}(t) = \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}$$
$$\left(a\, \text{sinc}(at)-b\,\text{sinc}(bt)\right)^2=$$ $$\frac{1}{\pi ^2 t^2}-\frac{\cos (2 \pi  a t)}{2 \pi ^2
   t^2}-\frac{\cos (2 \pi  b t)}{2 \pi
   ^2 t^2}-\frac{2 \cos (\pi   (a-b)t)}{\pi ^2
   t^2}+\frac{2 \cos (\pi  (a+b)t)}{\pi ^2
   t^2}$$ So, using Euler representation of the trigonometric functions, the antiderivative is given in terms of the exponential integral function $\text{Ei}(.)$, the sine and cosine integral functions and the sine and cosine functions.
Even simpler
$$\int \frac{\cos (c t)}{t^2}\,dt=-c\, \text{Si}(c t)-\frac{\cos (c t)}{t}$$
Using the bounds
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(a\, \text{sinc}(at)-b\,\text{sinc}(bt)\right)^2\,dt= | a| +| b|+| a-b| -| a+b|$$
If $a$ and $b$ are positive $I=| a-b|$.
Edit
We can make it more general considering
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\big(a\, \text{sinc}(bt)-c\,\text{sinc}(dt)\big)^2$$ and obtain
$$I=\frac {a^2}{b^2} |b|+\frac {c^2}{d^2} |d|+\frac {ac}{bd} (| b-d| -| b+d| )$$ If $(a,b,c,d)$ are all positive
$$I=\frac{a c | b-d| +(a-c) (a d-b c)}{b d}$$
